# How can I verify that my textfield is empty?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

```
    def check_full_name(self):
        toast("You have to enter your full name to use the app correctly ! ")
```

```
    MDTextFieldRound:
        id:user_app
        hint_text: "Full Name"
        size_hint_x:  None
        size_hint_y: 0.08
        width: 247
        font_size: 18
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.62}
        on_release: app.check_full_name() if user_app.text == '' else app.root.current = "accueil"
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, I want that when a field is empty calls my check_full_name function.Thanks for answering

Comment: So you just want your toast to appear just once? Or appearing when leave it blank like type in then delete all then unfocus it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, this should fix your problem:

**.py file**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.toast import toast

class PyApp(MDApp):
    def on_start(self):
        if self.root.ids.user_app.text == '':
            self.check_full_name() 
        else: 
            self.root.ids.user_app.current = "accueil"
    def check_full_name(self):
        toast("You have to enter your full name to use the app correctly ! ")

PyApp().run()
```

**.kv file**

```
FloatLayout:
    MDTextFieldRound:
        id:user_app
        hint_text: "Full Name"
        size_hint_x:  None
        size_hint_y: 0.08
        width: 247
        font_size: 18
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.62}
        on_text_validate: app.on_start()
```

Comment: can I apply the function on_start to a button ?

Comment: @MagneticKyubi Yes, you can.

Comment: Bro it didn't work. here is the error that appears when i test it :    File "C:\Users\moliko\Desktop\Reviewin2 - Copie\register.kv", line 113, in <module>
     on_press: app.on_start_1()
   File "c:\Users\moliko\Desktop\Reviewin2 - Copie\ReviewinApp.py", line 71, in on_start_1
     if self.root.ids.user_app.text == 'g':
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Comment: I replaced the '' by a 'g'

Comment: @MagneticKyubi It works fine for me, could you show me your code?

Comment: I did the same function but I applied it to a button, I did on_press : app.on_start()
I precise, my kv file is on another page. I have a python file where I edit functions And a kv for the front.

Comment: @MagneticKyubi The problem may lie in another section of your code, that's why I ask for your full code since I can not guess based on your limited information.

Comment: Ok, I'll put my code on answers okay ? But it would be easier if you give me your discord.

Comment: I put my full code on answers brother

Answer (score 0):

````
class SplashScreenApp(MDApp):
    dialog = None
    def build(self):
        dialog = None
        self.title = "ReviewinApp"
        global sm 
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("splash.kv"))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("accueil.kv"))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file('conditions.kv'))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("register.kv"))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("faq.kv"))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("login.kv"))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("User2.kv"))
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        return sm
    def on_start(self):
        if self.root.ids.user_app.text == ' ':
           toast("Please register correctly")
        else:
            toast("It's okay")
    ```
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Finish !"
            font_size: "20sp"
            font_name: "OpenSans"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.07}
            halign: 'center'
            theme_text_color:'Custom'
            text_color: 255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 1
            size_hint: (0.58, 0.06)
            md_bg_color: 62/255, 216/255, 133/255, 1
            background_normal:''
            on_press: app.on_start()
    ```
    The python file and the kivy files are on different pages. One with extension .kv and one with .py
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not include your def Build() everything work correctly. The problem must lie in another section of your code (not your button and def on_start function).

Comment: Anyway, I don't think you can add those .kv file in your ScreenManager. Since ScreenManager only can add RelativeLayout like Screen or FloatLayout, you can find more information [Here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html)